# Translations of QMessageBox not work in Qt5.3

Tags: qt, qt5.3

I'm a fan of Qt and update it frequently, Qt5.1->5.2->5.3.

However, the tranalations of Standard buttons like "Ok" "Cancel" "Save" do not work anymore in Qt5.3.
They are not translated, but just plain English.

The Code for translations does **NOT** change through each version of Qt.
like:

```
TRANSLATIONS = qt_fr.ts
QTranslator trans
trans.load("qt_fr");
a.installTranslator(&trans);
```

any idea?

**[Update]**
AFAIN, it might be a bug. Go back to Qt5.1 is a slution if U dont have to use some improvements in new Qts.

Comment: If your program works right under Qt 5.2 and the exact same program does not work right Qt 5.3, it's probably a Qt bug and your best option is to report it to Digia.  Be sure to include a small compileable example program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, I have the same problem, what OS do you use?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks, ur right. i way back to Qt5.1.

Comment: @JulienLopez win7/8/xp, it's a bug(or some reason i havent figured out). suggest u to way back to Qt5.1 if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Qt5.3 the `qt_*.qm` is divided into multiple files (`qt*_*.qm`) and now you have to copy `qtbase_*.qm` to translation directory and use together.

```
QString translationsPath(QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
QLocale locale = QLocale::system();

QTranslator qtTranslator;
if (qtTranslator.load(locale, "qt", "_", translationsPath))
    a.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);

QTranslator qtBaseTranslator;
if (qtBaseTranslator.load(locale, "qtbase", "_", translationsPath))
    a.installTranslator(&qtBaseTranslator);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and got it to work with an updated translation file. I am not sure if this is the intended behaviour, but my `qt_de.qm` has a filesize of only 1kB. There is however a file called `qtbase_de.qm` now (154kB) which seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This is source of qt_ru:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE TS>
    <TS version="2.0" language="ru">
    <dependencies>
        <dependency catalog="qtbase_ru"/>
        <dependency catalog="qtscript_ru"/>
        <dependency catalog="qtquick1_ru"/>
        <dependency catalog="qtmultimedia_ru"/>
        <dependency catalog="qtxmlpatterns_ru"/>
    </dependencies>
    </TS>
```

Therefore, it is necessary to deploy application with all these translation files. If at least one file is missing, the translation `qt_ru` will not load.