# How can I include C:\Qt\5.9.1\msvc2015\translations .qm files (Qt framework qm files) in Visual Studio Qt project?

Tags: qt, localization, qtranslator

How can I include C:\Qt\5.9.1\msvc2015\translations .qm files (Qt framework qm files) in final release, Visual Studio Qt project?

I am loading the files using:

```
    QTranslator* qtTranslator = new QTranslator();
bool ok = qtTranslator->load("qt_" + language, QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
```

in release and debug the translations work, but in the final build they don't and it is most probable that it's because they are not added.

I noticed that if i move them in my project they are not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qt framework translation files have to be added in the project translations folder together with qt_xx.qm, the correspondent qm dependency files have to be added.

qt_xx.qm contains only the name of those files - there is another answer explaining this here: [Translations of QMessageBox not work in Qt5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850108/translations-of-qmessagebox-not-work-in-qt5-3)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
QTranslator translator;   
if(translator.load("E:/Qt/Linguist/translation_fa.qm"))
    qDebug()<<"successfully load qm file.";
else
    qDebug()<<"problem in load qm file.";
```